# How to remove a Ubuntu distro on a system with 2 or more ubuntu distros already installed and without damaging grub?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, grub2, uninstall, 19.04

On a machine that is installed with two or more ubuntu distros, I want to remove one of the distro. How can I do so without damaging grub?

Example, if I want to remove Ubuntu distro in `/dev/sda`, what are the steps? Assuming I am login to Ubuntu in `/dev/nvme0n1`, do I use Gparted to clean out `/dev/sda`, then run `sudo update-grub` and that its? Or must I login using a Ubuntu 'Live' disk and do these procedures?

Thanks.

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000LX015-1U71 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name              Flags
 2      250MB   32.3GB  32.0GB  linux-swap(v1)  swap
 3      32.3GB  57.3GB  25.0GB  ext4            ubuntu18.04_root
 4      57.3GB  482GB   425GB   ext4            ubuntu18.04_home


Model: BPX (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 480GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   34.1GB  33.6GB  linux-swap(v1)  swap
 3      34.1GB  59.1GB  25.0GB  ext4            ubuntu18.04_root
 4      59.1GB  479GB   420GB   ext4            ubuntu18.04_home
```

Here is a link to the [/boot/grub/grub.cfg](https://gist.github.com/sunbearc22/ba84204b16b3d3372f588552b9f5e225)

Comment: To start with run command `sudo parted -l` and post output into question. Also post output of `gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: "How can I do so without damaging grub?"
 Why is that an issue you need to concern yourself with? Use boot repair if there is an issue. Oh and whatever you do: you will make backups of course.

Comment: My take on this situation is that all depends on which of the OS installed GRUB on the first place. So, I would say that running `grub-install` from the system you are going to keep wolud be enough. After removing the other OS you should run `update-grub`. But I don't know for sure :/.

Comment: @PaulBenson I have uploaded those info you had asked for.

Comment: @Rinzwind  I recalled an old experience of not being able to boot up after removing a distro and then having to use cli to issue commands to help fix grub. This time around, I would like to know what is the proper proceed so I can boot up cleanly again.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Thanks for your pointers. I have updated my question with what i think I should do. Correct?

Comment: Looks like you have separate home partitions on the two devices.  Make sure you backup the one you are going to delete.